# question 1 is repeat 2 time in this quiz project in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in my terminal the random listed properly and the questions are properly ordered, but question 1 is repeated twice.

code

```
genrandomarray() {
        var distinctIds = [];
        var rand =  Random();
        for (int i = 1;;) {
          distinctIds.add(rand.nextInt(10) + i);
          random_array = distinctIds.toSet().toList();
          if (random_array.length <10) {
            continue;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        print(random_array);
      }


void nextquestion() {
    canceltimer = false;
    timer = 10;
    setState(() {
      if (j < 10) {
        i = random_array[j];
        j++;
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => resultpage(marks: marks),
        ));
      }
```

Comment: Where are u defining `j` and what's its initial value?